# Regex: match string with or without quote

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to extract a value using regex.
This value can be quoted or not:

For example:

`foo: "bar"`
or
`foo: 'bar'`
or
`foo: bar`

How can I extract only `bar` value?

Here is the regex I use:

- `^(foo):\s+(.*)` --> works well to extract `bar` from `foo: bar` (https://regex101.com/r/cyZiId/1)
- `^(foo):\s+'(.*)'` --> works well to extract `bar` from `foo: 'bar'` (https://regex101.com/r/tjbVRq/1)
- `^(foo):\s+"(.*)"` --> works well to extract `bar` from `foo: "bar"` (https://regex101.com/r/kLnf6m/1)

How can I combine all three?

I don't want to use the first regex because it matches also the quotes `"bar"` and I only want to keep the string without the quotes.

Note that I would like to conserve the groups

Comment: Branch reset group - `foo:\s*(?|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'|(\w+))` - see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Ugjjj/1).

Comment: That looks like YAML. Is it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, branch reset group works perfectly fine!

Comment: Now, you understand why I did not post the answer. Always indicate the regex library, programming language or the tool where the regex is used.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this single regex with an additional capture group with an optional match and back-reference for all 3 cases:

```bash
^(foo):\s*(["']?)(\w.*?)(?<=\w)\2$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/djZeWM/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(foo)`: match `foo` in capture group #1
- `:\s*`: Match `:` followed by 0 or more whitespaces
- `(["']?)`: Optionally match `'` or `"` in capture group #2
- `(\w.*?)`: Match a word character followed by 0 more characters in capture group #3
- `(?<=\w)`: Make sure we have a word character on LHS of the current position
- `\2`: Match same character as what we capture in group #2
- `$`: End

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression will match the desired string.

```
rgx = /\Afoo:\s*(["']?)\K[^'"]*(?=\1\s*\z)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AykscJ/1)

For example:

```
"foo: 'bar'"[rgx] #=> "bar"
'foo: "bar"'[rgx] #=> "bar"
"foo: bar"[rgx]   #=> "bar"
```

The expression can be expressed in free-spacing mode to make it self-documenting:

```
rgx = /
  \A          # match beginning of the string
  foo:\s*     # match literal then >= 0 whitespaces
  (["']?)     # match ", ' or empty string and save to capture group 1 
  \K          # reset start of match and discard all previously-
              # consumed chars from the match that is returned
  [^'"]*      # match >= 0 characters other than ' and "
  (?=\1\s*\z) # positive lookahead asserts match is followed by
              # contents of capture group 1 then >= 0
              # whitespaces then end of string
/x            # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Comment: Very good use of match reset `\K`

Answer (score -1):

This regex would solve your specific use case: `^(foo):\s+['"]*([^'"]*)`
https://regex101.com/r/XJkzOj/1

If you give me more context about what you're trying to do I might be able to help more.

Good luck!